# "cannot create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list: Directory nonexistent" while upgrading getdeb-repository package

Tags: apt, dpkg

whenever I try to intall any packages the following bug comes up (OS in ubuntu 14.04).

```
anil@anil-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for anil: 
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpcap0.8:i386 wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up getdeb-repository (0.1-1~getdeb1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/getdeb-repository.postinst: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/getdeb-repository.postinst: cannot create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list: Directory nonexistent
dpkg: error processing package getdeb-repository (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 getdeb-repository
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
anil@anil-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder doesn't exist in the system.

Check if folder is present with:

```
   ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and if it is missing, try:

```
  sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and redo `apt-get` command.